# Is there a possibility OnChange doesnt shoot?

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes, onchange, uppercase

probably someone has a idea:
We want to force the users to write in a `textbox` called txtShirtName just in Uppercase.
To force this, we add this attribute:

```
txtShirtName.Attributes["onchange"] = "this.value = this.value.ToUpperCase();";
```

But some time ago, we found some database entries, which wasn't uppercase. Since we can log how this was created, we can say it was from a user, but not directly who it was.

So my question: Do you see any possibility, how the `onchange` could not shoot?

Comment: Why don't you _uppercase_ on serverside? I would do it on server- and on clientside.

Comment: It was probably a copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this functionality is so important for you so you should handle it on client side and server side too .. so now you now you will be 100% sure that the data will be upper case even if the onchange didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has JS deactivated, the onChange event won't work. If you want the input to be uppercase you have to do this on server side. JS validation/manipulation can easily be bypassed.